# Combine multiple media queries with classes inside

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I want to create a mixin which adds multiple media queries to a class.

Is their any way to combine media queries with classes which are inside a mixin but sharing the same content?

My goal is to reduce duplicate code in the best possible way.

```
=constructor()
    @content

    @media (min-width: $tablet)

        &-tablet
            @content

    @media (min-width: $tabletAndPC)

        &-tablet-pc
            @content

    @media (min-width: $tabletAndPC) and ($touchDevice)

        &-tablet-pc
            @content

    @media (min-width: $pc)

        &-pc
            @content

    @media (min-aspect-ratio: $ultrawideRatio) and (min-width: $ultrawide)

        &-ultrawide
            @content

    @media (min-aspect-ratio: $superUltrawideRatio) and (min-width: $ultrawide)

        &-super-ultrawide
            @content
```

---

I'm using this mixin for every class I want to have a responsive class.

Something like this:
class="element element-lg-pc"

An element which changes his size on a specific media query.

```
.element
     +constructor()
          // basic class code

     &-lg
         +constructor()
             // basic class code + size specific code
```

Comment: Are you asking how to reduce this snippet further, or how to make it work (it seems to work)?

Comment: To reduce it because my css file is getting way to big with this.

Comment: How is it used?

Comment: @Ry- Read my answers.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add information. How do the `-tablet`, `-pc`, etc. suffixes work? Do they not actually apply the same styles in the real code?

Comment: @Ry- Thanks for changing. I'm currently using the Stack Exchange App and couldn't delete my Answer myself.

Comment: @Ry- Yes -tablet, -pc etc.. have the same styles.

Comment: Then what’s their purpose? Does `element element-lg-pc` mean the element should only be large on a pc?

Comment: @Ry- Yes, that's the purpose.

Comment: Do you find this often being element-instance-specific instead of class-specific (e.g. compared to `class="element"` and placing the relevant media queries on `.element` using a mixin for each environment)? (Because if not, that’s probably a good start to making the output shorter.)

Comment: @Ry- I don't think this would help if I have something like this - > class="element-sm element-lg-pc element-xl-ultrawide"